# Journey Builder Versions

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking at previous versions of one journey in the drop down, and can see 3 journeys in the 'finishing' status. Should I manually stop them and how is it indicated that a journey has actually finished? thanks for any advice, Ian

Answer (score 2):

*Finishing* status means, that they don't receive new contacts, as these are pointed towards the Active version of the journey. In addition to *Finishing* journeys can also have status of *Draft*, *Active*, *Paused* and *Stopped*. I am trying to explain the different statuses a journey can have:

- **Draft**: The journey is currently being worked on, and is not yet activated. As soon as you activate, previous version (if exists) is switched to *Finishing* status. Journey in *Draft* status doesn't accept contacts.
- **Active**: The journey has been activated, and is now accepting contacts.
- **Finishing**: A newer version of the journey has been activated, and the contacts currently in the Finishing journey are moving through it as per design. No new contacts are being accepted.
- **Paused**: An active journey has been paused. While pausing a journey, you can queue any contacts entering a paused journey and process them after the journey resumes. You can also drop the contacts trying to enter a paused journey. Contacts currently in a journey are not moving forward to the next activities while paused.
- **Stopped**: You can stop a finishing journey completely, which will kick out all the contacts currently in the journey, regardless where they are.

Comment: thanks Lukas. Do I need to manually 'stop' them after no more contacts enter the journey?

Comment: @user2382031 there is no need to stop them. They will either way not accept new contacts. Remember to mark the answer as accepted, if it has been helpful.

Comment: hi, I seem unable to mark the answer. I think it may be voting priveleges that I do not have but thanks anyway

Comment: @user2382031 you should just click on the check mark, as you indeed need a higher score to be able to upvote